# How to validate an uploaded file a csv or not with out using content type property (with out checking the extension) of file upload control in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, file-upload, content-type

I need to check whether an upload file a csv or not with out checking the file extension. Using filecontent property also i can't find the type efficiently if a non-csv file is  renamed to ".csv" extension. I need to prevent such things from happening.

Any one please suggest a method to find the content type by reading header info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following code which reads the first 256 bytes from the file and return the mime type of the file using an internal dll (urlmon.dll)..

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

```
[DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
    System.UInt32 pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
    System.UInt32 cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
    System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
    out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
    System.UInt32 dwReserverd
);

public string getMimeFromFile(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " not found");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (fs.Length >= 256)
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
        else
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    }
    try
    {
        System.UInt32 mimetype;
        FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
        System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
        return mime;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "unknown/unknown";
    }
}
```

But check the type in different browsers, since the mimetype might be different in different browsers.

Also this will give the exact mimetype even if you changed the extension...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to parse the file as CSV - if it parses OK, it is CSV, if not, it isn't.

You could use a parser such as the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that is part of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Text` namespace.

Comment: It's an old post. any help will be really nice. I am using the same, but its not working expected. .jpeg file also passing the test.i afraid can't attach screen shot in comment